# Attachment from Data Driven Pages - Name Filter

Tags: arcgis-desktop, data-driven-pages, filter, arcgis-collector, attachments

We are using data driven pages to create a large series of figures.  We used Collector in the field to collect features with data and attachments.

To display the attachments for each feature, we use the "Attachment from Data Driven Pages" and the "Name Filter" option.

The problem we run into is some field devices save attachments as "Attachment1" (Android) or "Photo1" (Apple).  Is there a way to use a wild card or use multiple names in the "Name Filter"?

Comment: What are the extensions of those attachments?

Comment: I'd simply rename attachment during it's transfer to a page.

Comment: Renaming the attachments is difficult.  You have to save all the attachments for specific records, delete them, rename them, and re-attach.

The extension is .jpg